# How to group database table data by two columns and output as json?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to get JSON(PHP) from PhpMyAdmin(Mysql). It actually need to look like:

```
[{ “converterno”: ”1”, “zoneno”: {“1a”, “codeid”:[“t1”,”t2”,”t3”]}, “zoneno”: {“1b”, “codeid”:[“t21”,”t0”,”t13”]}},{ “converterno”: ”2”, “zoneno”: {“2a”, “codeid”:[“t023”,”t9”,”t31”]}},………………………..
```

But what I am actually getting is

```
[{"converternumber":"1","zonenumber":{"0":"","codeid":["er"]}},{"converternumber":"1","zonenumber":{"0":"wr","codeid":["fxv"]}},{"converternumber":"2","zonenumber":{"0":"b2","codeid":["gffff"]}}]
```

> And I don't know why I am getting Zero's at the starting

The PHP code is:

```
<?php
$db_name="app1";
$mysql_user="root";
$server_name="localhost";

$connectionn=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,"",$db_name);
$n_converternumber= ["converternumber"];
$n_zonenumber= ["zonenumber"];
$n_codeid= ["codeid"];

$sql_query = "select * from addcode";
$result= mysqli_query($connectionn,$sql_query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  if(!isset($info[$row['converternumber']])){
    $info[$row['converternumber']] = array(
      'converternumber'=> $row['converternumber'],
      'zonenumber' => array($row['zonenumber'],
      'codeid' => array($row['codeid']))
    );
}}
echo json_encode($info);
?>
```

Can anyone kindly tell me where I am going wrong in the "While" loop.

Went through all the code relating to JSON in **StackOverFlow**, but didn't find anything closer or similar. Tried almost everything and posting this now!!
Hope I would get any help here!

The table in the database is:
[Table addcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH8Ia.png)

Comment: I think - contrary to @MadhurBhaiya (sorry) - that you don't want the array for zonenumber at all: `...'zonenumber' => $row['zonenumber'],
      'codeid' => $row['codeid']..`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya and @mickmackusa , it's not a typo or a double  to be clear, I opened the array at `array( $row['zonenumber']........array($row['codeid]) )` and closed here. I want to do something like this. [link](http://api.androiddeft.com/cities/cities_array.json). So please recheck the question, maybe I don't need the array for zone but I am not getting the desired result and I am doing Trial-and-error now and then by putting arrays and removing them.  Hope you will help me. Kindly refer to @Nigel Ren solution. It isn't working though, but I think he/she understood the question well.

Comment: Are you happy for zone to be a string value in your desired result?  If so, please update your question.

Comment: yes @mickmackusa. Zone is 'varchar'. Also I cannot get the desired result after trying many methods. I'll update the my another code which I have tried shortly.

Comment: @mickmackusa done

Comment: yes @mickmackusa there are some null's but the thing is I want something like `[{ “converterno”: ”1”, “zoneno”: [“1a”], “codeid”:[“t1”,”t2”,”t3”]}.......` I am struggling for this since long time. lol.

Comment: Hey I updated database. So no nulls now. Everything is a key and combination of three (converterno., zoneno., codeid) is a primary key @mickmackusa

Comment: yes @mickmackusa. Thankyou!

Comment: I would vote for myself if I had option to. lol

Comment: @mickmackusa I was the one missing vote to re-open...done now.

Answer (score 0):

After extended discusson, you seem to desire a "grandparent-parent-child" structure.  This is super easy to form and a completely associative structure will keep your data very compact and simple to iterate.

*and you should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of the bloating `mysqli_fetch_array()` because you don't intend to use the indexed elements that it generates.

Code ([Demo based on your database screenshot](https://3v4l.org/p8cFJ))

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $info[$row['converternumber']][$row['zonenumber']][] = $row['codeid'];
}
```

The 3-level array would look like this:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    '1a' => 
    array (
      0 => 'test007',
      1 => 'test006',
      2 => 'test0094',
      3 => 'test0098',
      4 => 'test010',
      5 => 'test111',
      6 => 'test 008',
      7 => 'test112',
      8 => 'test004',
      9 => 'test002',
      10 => 'test001',
    ),
    23 => 
    array (
      0 => 'rg',
    ),
    '2a' => 
    array (
      0 => 'test001',
      1 => 'test003',
    ),
    'feh' => 
    array (
      0 => 'ndo',
    ),
    'wr' => 
    array (
      0 => 'fxv',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    '1a' => 
    array (
      0 => 'test',
    ),
    'b2' => 
    array (
      0 => 'gffff',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: @Arvind do you know how to enter the chat room?  Or have you had enough and wish me to go away?

Comment: @Arvind I've updated ...again. In fact, I've mostly reverted my answer to a previous version where I suggested using a composite temporary key to assist in efficient grouping.  I've also written the empty intitial data that you mentioned in our discussion.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I already got this earlier, but I don not want the converter numbers to be repeating like that . To be precise, I want like
`[{ “converterno”: ”1”, “zoneno”: {“1a”, “codeid”:[“t1”,”t2”,”t3”]}, “zoneno”: {“1b”, “codeid”:[“t21”,”t0”,”t13”]}},{ “converterno”: ”2”, “zoneno”: {“2a”, “codeid”:[“t023”,”t9”,”t31”]}},……………………….. `
Hope I will get the result

Comment: What you are asking for now is literally impossible.  You will never have an array that has two `zoneno` keys in the same level.  Let me know when you have a valid array structure.  I feel like I am repeating myself now, but this is why I was urging you to use a nested and fully associative array structure.

Comment: `{"1":{"wr":["fxv"],"feh":["ndo"],"23":["rg"],"2a":["test","test001"],"1a":["test 008","test006","test007","test008","test009","test0094","test0098","test010","test111","test112"],"a1":["test001","test002","test003","test004"],"12":["yx"]},"2":{"b2":["gffff"],"1a":["test"]},"19":{"sb":["sb"]}}`

Let me be very very clear this time, the above JSON is what you gave me. I just want to label them "1"as converter, "wr,feh, 23 and so on" as zones and "fxv, ndo, rg and so on" as codes. Hope you understand it now. @mickmackusa

Comment: I was conveying you the same since you posted the answer. but we had a miscommunication @mickmackusa

Comment: I have just done my second and final rollback.  I am completely exhausted by this question.  I have shown you the best way to store your data.  Explaining how to process the data to suit your application is beyond the question scope.  I will encourage you to ask a new question.  I am enjoying the weekend with my family.

Comment: Thanks for the time but it isn't helping. Working on the same issue all these days. I just wanted as shown in the question for the code convenience, Unnamed JSON objects to Named JSON objects, You gave me unnamed, I wanted named

Thanks,
I'll try Harder!